# c++ std::vector "this" was "nullptr"

Tags: c++, vector, smart-pointers, init, nullptr

for some reason I can not use the vector _vec in datacenter.cpp. It says "**this**" was "nullptr"

please help, thanks <3

**datacenter.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class datacenter
{
public:
    datacenter();
    ~datacenter();

    void get_elements();

    std::vector<float> _vec;
};
```

**datacenter.cpp**

```
#include "datacenter.h"

datacenter::datacenter(){}

void datacenter::get_elements()
{
if (_vec.empty()) { //<---- the error appears here
    std::cout << "empty" << std::endl;
    }
}

datacenter::~datacenter(){}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "datacenter.h"

class datacenter;

int main()
{
std::unique_ptr<datacenter> dc;
dc->get_elements();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The trouble comes from:

```
std::unique_ptr<datacenter> dc;
```

This does not create an instance of `datacenter`, but only a (null) (smart) pointer to it. You need to create an instance with:

```
auto dc = std::make_unique<datacenter>();
```

#### See also

- [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) (especially its [default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr))
- [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique)

Answer (score 4):

A `std::unique_ptr` is a container of an object, the object contained must be initialized as if it were a non-smart pointer, it's not automatically constructed with black magic.

What you are doing is roughly equivalent to

```
datacenter* dc = nullptr;
dc->get_elements();
```

You need to istantiate the object first:

```
auto dc = std::make_unique<datacenter>();
```

Mind that you are lucky you were using a `std::unique_ptr` because a non initialized variable would have contained a garbage value (instead that `nullptr`) making debugging harder in a real life example.

Answer (score -1):

You unique pointer is not initialized and its content is null. 
You should initialize it this way :

```
std::unique_ptr<datacenter> dc = std::unique_ptr<datacenter>(new datacenter());
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b54fa5fc05396e65

Comment: or with make_unique, if you use std::c++14 and beyond